# Script that execute C by Bash

Tags: c, bash

What should a script that compiles and executes a C program look like?
By condition, the script must be run with the following flags:
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -o

In my understanding, when running the script, I have to enter the name of the program file

```
% gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra "file_name".c -o "file_name"
% ./"file_name"
```

Comment: What you have is not unreasonable, but you probably should not execute the code unless it is built successfully.  ie, `gcc ... "$file".c && ./"$file"`.

Comment: Related? https://github.com/ryanmjacobs/c

Comment: There could be strong cybersecurity issues. You need to trust the human who gave you that C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script can take the name of the program as an argument, which you access using `$1`. Then substitute that for the file name in the commands.

```
#!/bin/sh

prog="$1"

if gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra "$prog".c -o "$prog"
then "./$prog"
else
    echo "$prog.c did not compile successfully"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra "$1".c -o "$1" && "./$1" || echo "Unable to compile and run $1"
```

Compile with gcc and run a program if it is successfully compiled, otherwise show the message to user.

Run the script like

```
script_name file_name
```